# xdsoft datepicker || get value from two different datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetimepicker

my problem is:
i have two different date picker, one for date and one for time.
i try to get the selected date,and time value with php $_GET[];. 
when i select date, i get date value but when i select time i lose date, but i get time or inversely. so my question is how can i append this two value?

thanks ( sorry for my bad English)

**Here is the code:**

```
    jQuery('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  datepicker:false,
  format:'H:i',

      onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){

    var selected_time = $input.val()
     window.location.search ="time="+ selected_time;

  }
});


jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
  format:'Y-m-d',
  inline:true,
  timepicker:false,
    onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
    var selected_date_time2 = document.getElementById("datetimepicker2").value; 
    var selected_date_time = $input.val()

     window.location.search ="date=" + selected_date_time+"&";

  }

});
```

Comment: Looks like you are using `window.location.search =` to set the parameters in each instance. When you set one you overwrite the other. Since you're already using jQuery I would suggest taking a look at [`jQuery.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/), which should offer greater flexibility. You could also wait for the form to be submitted, which will automatically add those fields as GET parameters (if you give them a name attribute).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion tshimkus,
to the solve my problem is used : localStorage.setItem()
its working, but i dont like it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with localStorage

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  datepicker:false,
  format:'H:i',
  stepping: 15,

      onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){

    var selected_time = $input.val()
    localStorage.setItem("time", selected_time);
    var date = localStorage.getItem("date");
     window.location.search ="date="+date+"&time="+selected_time;

  }
});


jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
  format:'Y-m-d',
  inline:true,
  timepicker:false,
  dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    onChangeDateTime:function(dp,$input){
    var selected_date_time2 = document.getElementById("datetimepicker2").value; 
    var selected_date = $input.val()
    localStorage.setItem("date", selected_date);    
    var time = localStorage.getItem("time");
     window.location.search ="date="+selected_date+"&time="+time;

  }

});
```